# What tag should be used for questions on typography?

Tags: discussion, tags

Typography seems to me a part of writing. Things like fonts, kerning, typographical styling (bold, italics etc.), drop caps, small caps... Do we have a tag that covers those? Or do I go ahead and create one?

Comment: While those subjects can be a part of the writing process, you might also get good answers over on [graphicdesign.se].

Comment: @aCVn Here's a question, for example, that could go under [typography] here, but wouldn't fit [graphicdesign.se]: https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43096/14704 (I had it in mind when I asked this question here.)

Comment: @aCVn and here's another one, not mine this time: https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/43100/14704

Comment: There is a formatting tag

Comment: @prosepraise I am answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making my comment an actual answer, there is already a formatting tag.